# SQL check time difference hours between record and dateTime now

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add to this query an additional "AND" to check if the time between two records is at least 2 hours. This is the original query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Viewed) FROM [Views] WHERE userIP  = @userIP AND MessageID=@MessageID
```

I tried adding a second AND like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Viewed) FROM [Views] WHERE userIP = @userIP
AND MessageID=@MessageID
AND (@Now - dateTime)>2
```

and also like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Viewed) FROM [Views] WHERE userIP = @userIP
AND MessageID=@MessageID
AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, @Now, dateTime)>2
```

@Now = datetime now, (2015-01-26 09:08:28.183)

dateTime= the datetime in the table of the posted record (2015-01-25 11:06:15.001

But I am not getting the result. How to do this?

Comment: `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[dateTime],@Now) > 120`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, [dateTime], @Now) > (2 * 60 * 60)
```

This assumes your [dateTime] values are all in the past. If they could be in the future too then wrap it in ABS().

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly put the value in `Datediff()`, use @now as last parameter

```
DECLARE @OMG Datetime
SET @OMG = '2015-01-25 11:06:15.001'

SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, @OMG, GETDATE())

IF (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @OMG, GETDATE()) > 2)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Yes'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NO'
    END
```